# ZTE Blade/San Francisco memory cards that work

Tags: external-sd, ram, zte-blade

I'm looking out to extend the card memory for my [ZTE Blade](http://www.gsmarena.com/zte_blade-3391.php) phone.

Can anybody who has experience with this tell me which SD cards (preferably 16GB and above) certainly work well for the San Francisco/ZTE Blade phone? If you're using this phone with an SD card model that works, please tell me which one.

Note: many people seem to report that some SD cards do not work well with this phone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this discussion at MoDaCo](http://android.modaco.com/content/zte-blade-blade-modaco-com/327434/16gb-sd-cards-that-definitely-work/) about the issue.  It includes cards that people have tried and found to work.

The generally consensus seems to be that Sandisk 16 GB Class 2 cards work.  Kingston 16 GB Class 4 worked for a couple people, but not for another until they tried deleting everything on it via Windows XP.  I personally wouldn't go lower than a Class 4 card, and I'm partial to Kingston.

Comment: What is the difference between Class X cards? The higher the number X, better the quality? Or speed?

Comment: @axel22 Write speed in MB/s. I believe higher class cards also have higher read speeds. Quality is largely independent though.